# return number of unique dates on another sheet in the same workbook

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

I have a project for work where I am trying to calculate the total number of days an employee worked, with data from one sheet feeding the number calculated on the same sheet, or another sheet in the same workbook.

There are several rows of data for each work day, and so I am looking to calculate the total number of unique dates for each employee separately. If the data is isolated to one employee then I can use:

```
=SUM(IF(FREQUENCY(B:B,B:B)>0,1))
```

to calculate the number of work days. I have tried using several additional formulas to get the value I'm looking for, including:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((TEXT('Data'!$A$1:$A$100, "yyyymm")="201804")*('Data'!B$1:$B$100="John Doe"))
```

AND

```
=SUMIFS(IF(FREQUENCY('Sono Detail'!$B:$B,'Sono Detail'!$B:$B)>0,1),'Sono Detail'!$E:$E,'(Test) Sono Report Card 1.0'!$B$3)
```

Neither of these worked.

Comment: @ScottCraner, Any ideas?

Comment: Here is an example sheet that you can use to play with.
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1gyU78sccXMmFxCvEcDikIIUGcj7J8yrRGJOWNG762qo/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Why not use a PivotTable?

Comment: @PeterT, How would I do that and still get the information I need. I'm trying to use this data to drive further calculations.

Comment: You would create a PivotCache from your original data set, then create a PivotTable using that cache (probably in a temporary worksheet). In the pivot table, add the Employee field as a datarow (`.Orientation = xlRowField`) and then add "Count of Work Dates" as the data field (`.AddDataField`). (You'll have to use whatever names of fields you're using of course.) Finally, you can run down each row and see how many days each person worked to use in later calculations -- or even snap that pivot table data into an array/dictionary for quicker access and lookups.

Comment: @PeterT I just tried to do this. It was a great idea. The problem was that each day has multiple rows of data. The results that I got were really inflated. I should get results no greater than 22, but I'm getting numbers between 200 and 400. That is why I think I'll have to go the formula route.

Have you reviewed the link I shared?

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a code solution (yet), but I'm posting this answer to illustrate the data you can derive from a pivot table based on the sample you provided.

In the first arrangement of fields, you can see that the pivot shows how many procedures were performed on each day for each employee. This includes an overall total number of procedures for each employee for the time period. So "Employee 1" performed 14 procedures on 1-March, and so on.

[image]

If I change the Values field of the pivot, I can show the total time (in **DAYS**) that each employee spent performing procedures. So in the table below, Employee 1 worked 0.15833 Days on 1-March. This translates to 288 minutes (or 3.8 hours).

[image]

VBA code to traverse the pivot table would then identify each employee and how many days they worked and can access other summative data as well.

Comment: T good thinking. I really like where this line of reasoning takes us and I think that I can get some good data from this, but the total time working isn't = to the total shift. The times listed are for a type of event performed.

Comment: Your data does not include any indication of the type of event performed, so I wouldn't expect it to show (for example) an 8 hour shift for Employee 1 on 1-March. If you have more data than what's in your example, I encourage you to pull it into the pivot table and play around with how to sort and sift it to get the totals you believe are there.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I'll have to look at pivot tables for more information. The example I provided includes all the data needed to calculate the total number of days worked per employee.

Answer (score 0):

If you can use VBA macros, then try this:

in cell L3 type:

```
=WorkingDaysCount(B:B,C:C,K3)
```

Do similarly for the other employees in L4, L5, and L6.

Then use this code below in a new code module

```
Option Explicit

Public Function WorkingDaysCount(ByRef Dates As Range, ByRef EmployeeRange As Range, ByVal Employee As String) As Integer
    Dim ct As Integer 'counter
    Dim i As Long
    'for looping

    Dim EmployeeDates() As Date 'array to track which dates are already counted
    ReDim EmployeeDates(0)  'create initial

    'loop through all the cells
    For i = 1 To Dates.Count
        If (EmployeeRange(i) = Employee) Then   'if the employee is equal to the employee in that range
            If (Not (IsInArray(Dates(i), EmployeeDates))) Then  'if the date hasn't already been counted
                EmployeeDates(UBound(EmployeeDates)) = Dates(i) 'add the date
                ReDim Preserve EmployeeDates(UBound(EmployeeDates) + 1) 'add another element to the array for the next one
            End If
        End If
    Next i

    WorkingDaysCount = UBound(EmployeeDates)    'since ubound is 0-based this is the total count of dates
End Function

Private Function IsInArray(valToBeFound As Variant, arr As Variant) As Boolean
    'DEVELOPER: Ryan Wells (wellsr.com)
    'DESCRIPTION: Function to check if a value is in an array of values
    'INPUT: Pass the function a value to search for and an array of values of any data type.
    'OUTPUT: True if is in array, false otherwise
    Dim element As Variant
    On Error GoTo IsInArrayError: 'array is empty
        For Each element In arr
            If element = valToBeFound Then
                IsInArray = True
                Exit Function
            End If
        Next element
    Exit Function
IsInArrayError:
    On Error GoTo 0
    IsInArray = False
End Function
```